# delete record via AJAX when table are generated with JQuery append

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax

I have a html table with data. And i would like to delete records via `ajax` but i struggling little bit because my table are generated with `append`:

```
        ...
        $.each(data, function(id, won) {
                                if (data[i].flag == 0)   {flag='<img src="../images/flag-y.png"  width="20" height="20">'} else {flag='<img src="../images/flag.png"  width="20" height="20">'}

                             $el.append('<tr><td>'+data[i].id+'</td>
    <td><a href="?identifier='+data[i].id+'&token='+data[i].token+'"><img src="../images/edit.png"  width="20" height="20"></a></td>
 <td><a href="?delete='+data[i].id+'&deletetoken='+data[i].token+'"><img src="../images/delete.png"  width="20" height="20" class="delete"></td> </tr>');
                              i = ++ i;                                                                                       
                            } );
        ...
```

It works. but how to pass parameter into ajax call if somebody clicks the picture on to last column (i don't need a help with php file)?

```
$('a.delete').click(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

     var parent = $(this).parent();
        $.ajax({
            type: 'get',
            url: 'jquery-record-delete.php',
            data: 'ajax=?delete,
            beforeSend: function() {
                parent.animate({'backgroundColor':'#fb6c6c'},300);
            },
            success: function() {
                parent.slideUp(300,function() {
                    parent.remove();
                });
            }
        });

    });
```

I need to pass delete and deletetoken variables.

Comment: Since your links are created dynamically, most likely after the event binding `$('a.delete').click(function(e) {...` is done, you will probably need to do event delegation, ie. `$(document).on('click', 'a.delete', function(e){`. You could also change the `document` to a parent selector that does not change.

Comment: @Sean Thanks. Is it possible to have more help in a code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest you add `data-id` attribute to each `<tr>`, like this:

```
$el.append('<tr data-id="+ data[i].id +" data-token="+ data[i].token +">
    + '<td>' + data[i].id + '</td>'
    + '<td>'
        + '<a href="?identifier=' + data[i].id + '&token=' + data[i].token + '">'
            + '<img src="../images/edit.png"  width="20" height="20">'
        + '</a>'
    + '</td>'
    + '<td>'
        + '<a href="?delete=' + data[i].id + '&deletetoken=' + data[i].token + '" class="delete">' // also, you listen to a.delete click, so let's add "delete" class to it
        + '<img src="../images/delete.png" width="20" height="20" class="delete">'
        + '</a>' // I think you were missing closing a tag here
    + '</td>'
+ '</tr>');
i++;
```

So you can grab it easily in the listener callback:

```
$('body').on('click', 'a.delete', function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var tr = $(this).closest('tr'),
        token = tr.data('token'),
        id = tr.data('id'); // we have the ID
    $.ajax({
        type: 'get',
        url: 'jquery-record-delete.php',
        data: {
            id: id, // passing id,
            token: token,
            ajax: 'delete'
        },
        beforeSend: function() {
            tr.animate({'backgroundColor':'#fb6c6c'},300);
        },
        success: function() {
            tr.slideUp(300,function() {
                tr.remove();
            });
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: This script is not firing on click anly submiting on another file

Comment: Of course, I've updated the answer. The reason for the click not to fire is because `a.delete` is a dynamic element.

Comment: Something happens but i can see the error `parent.animate is not a function`  in here  `parent.animate({'backgroundColor':'#fb6c6c'},300);`

Comment: How to pass two parameters?` '<tr data-id='+ data[i].id +'&token='+data[i].token +  '>`  and `data: {
            id: id, // passing id
            token: identifier // passing token
        },` returns something like `jquery-record-delete.php?id=69%26token%3Dc75cb66ae28d8ebc6eded002c28a8ba0d06d3a78c6b5cbf9b2ade051f0775ac4`

Comment: Use the same attitude: create `data-token` attribute on `tr`, add it to request params. I've updated the code.